# PostgreSQL start.conf not working

Tags: postgresql, 14.10

I've just upgraded to 14.10 from 14.04. I have both 9.3 and 9.4 versions of PostgreSQL installed but, for now and until i fully migrate to 9.4, i just want to start the 9.3 cluster.

I edited the start.conf file for the 9.4 cluster and changed the auto setting to manual but, when i do

> service postgresql start

both clusters start normally.

Am i doing something wrong? Am i missing something? Is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

Following command helped me to stop 9.4 service.

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.4 main stop
```

After this command when I run

```
service postgresql stop
service postgresql start
service postgresql status
```

I have following output

```
9.3/main (port 5432): online
9.4/main (port 5434): down
```

Comment: Thank, your answer work for me, ubuntu 14.04 version of postgres 9.3 and 9.4